# How to sum up columns of a dataset in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, sum, apache-spark

I am new to Spark/Scala. I have a dataset with many columns, each column has a column name. Given several column names (these column names are not fixed, they are generated dynamically), I need to sum up the values of these columns. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

I worked out a way by using for loop, but I don't think it is efficient:

```
val AllLabels = List("ID", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4")
val lbla = List("val1", "val3", "val4")
val index_lbla = lbla.map(x => AllLabels.indexOf(x))

val dataRDD = sc.textFile("../test.csv").map(_.split(","))

dataRDD.map(x=>
 {
  var sum = 0.0
  for (i <- 1 to index_lbla.length) 
    sum = sum + x(i).toDouble
  sum
 }
).collect
```

The test.csv looks like below (without column names):

```
"ID", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"
 A, 123, 523, 534, 893
 B, 536, 98, 1623, 98472
 C, 537, 89, 83640, 9265
 D, 7297, 98364, 9, 735
 ...
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop you mention is just syntactic sugar for some higher order functions like `map` in scala. You may want to read more about it.

In this case, you can replace the for loop processing with a `map` and `sum`.

```
dataRDD.map(x => index_lbla.map(i => x(i).toDouble).sum).collect

// note that this also fixes the error in selecting columns for summation in the original version.
```